# SSH to a docker container and execute a Java Program (PSVM)

Tags: java, docker

I am new to docker and struggling with my assignment question. It is to execute a Java program after SSH ing to the docker container .

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' 
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional 
pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"] 

FROM java:8
COPY . /var/www/java
WORKDIR /var/www/java
```

I was able to start the container but when i attempted to ping with the IPAddress i get no response .

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
10301156ddc7        sshsample           "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   37 
minutes ago      Up 37 minutes       22/tcp              
optimistic_bardeen
```

I do have the IP address in my etc/hosts file.

My questions are

1. Why is my ping to the container failing ?
2. I need to SSH into this container and then run a Java Program (PSVM) .

After i successfully resolve the pinging issue i am thinking of doing the following

```
$ssh root@172.17.0.2
```

Question is

How do i run a java program located in the container after SSH into it ? Executing

```
>Java HWorld.java will work from the bash shell ?
```

This is my first attempt @ learning docker and so i explained the best i can. Please help.

Comment: regarding your java question: first you have to compile your java source file (HWorld.java) to a binary class file, afterwards you can run that java program if it has the usual `public static void main(String[] args){}` entrypoint method: 

1) compile => `javac HWorld.java` (if successful HWorld.class file will be created in the same directory)
2) execute => `java HWorld`

Comment: Making an ssh connection into a Docker container is an extremely unusual setup.  You might read the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) for a more typical workflow.  That tutorial also explains how to publish ports to reach a server running in a container, which should get you connected.  Don't look up or try to use the container-internal IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't SSH into the container**

Your ping fails because the 2 containers you spin up is on different network. You may need to attach a common network between those two to make it to talk each other.

If your sole intention to SSH into the container is to execute the JAVA class here is how you do it:
HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World from Docker Container....");
    }
}
```

Write a Dockerfile as shown below and build a image -

```
docker build -t sujaypillai/helloworld-java .
```

[image]

Here is a good blog from [Docker](https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/) about why you don't need to SSH into container.

Comment: Thank you . This helped a lot .